# Intersections between two columns of equal number points

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, exponential-function, intersection-theory

[image]

How can I apply combinatorics to calculate the number of intersections between two columns of points? In the photo below let x be the number of point in each column, for x=2 we have 1 intersection, for x=3 we have 7 intersections and for x=4 we have  27 intersections. I'm asking because I'm not well versed in combinatorics, so I thank you in advance if you'll help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entry [A159065](http://oeis.org/A159065) in the OEIS.